# Strange form caching behaviour

Tags: html, django, forms

Am at a bit of a loss with a bug we've got on www.muchbetteradventures.com/ski/enquire/

(And, where to ask for help - is here appropriate!?)

What happens is..

About 1% of the time someone fills out the form and hits submit, some of the submitted fields contents are replaced by a previously submitted entry by a different person on a different machine (mostly the large textarea - or at least, this is the easiest to spot as it's pretty hard to exactly replicate someone else's entry)

In debugging this, I have been logging form contents both via Raven/Sentry on the frontend before it hits our server, and on the backend before any further processing. Both of these are always showing the same content that is actually saved to the DB by the underlying process - e.g. the duplicated content.

We've asked a few users what's happened from their point of view and they're telling us that they  have filled in a blank form with their own content. And that they have not seen someone elses content at any time.

What could be happening? Downstream cache somewhere is all I can think of.

Any help would be appreciated..!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like one of:

- **Race conditions**

  - Are you pre-generating the primary key of the object before the data actually gets saved in the database?  If so you might be having PK collisions and two form POSTs end up updating the same database row.
- **Non thread-safe code**

  - Are you deployed in a threaded environment?  If so are your views built in a thread-safe manor?  Django's class based views are thread-safe out of the box, but if you have something else driving view machinery (3rd party libraries, etc) it could be a threading issue.

Comment: The view is saving exactly what it's getting sent - Logging the form contents pre submit (via javascript) and post submit (first action of the 'post' view method is to log) show this. The client is posting the duplicate data. Sometimes the form is pre-populated with session data - so if there is a way for sessions to collide or be hijacked that could be it (if we ignore the users saying they filled in the form..)